# How to change the format of time for a specific column in SQL Server from hhmmss to hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query get the time for a column called "OBRGTM" is '112532'. I need to convert this format to '11:25:32' I mean from hhmmss to hh:mm:ss

Comment: do you want that In SQL Server?

Comment: yes please.....

Comment: the datetype is numeric

Comment: Consider fixing that schema while you're at it and use the proper data type.

Comment: A format has nothing to do with conversion. Is your column numeric (int)?

Answer (score 3):

If your SQL-server version support `FORMAT` method you can use this.

**TEST DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    dt numeric
);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (112532);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (012532);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (012530);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT FORMAT(dt,'0#:##:##')
FROM T
```

**[Results]**:

```
|          |
|----------|
| 11:25:32 |
| 01:25:32 |
| 01:25:30 |
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94562/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Use `LEFT` function to remove or eliminate the leading `0000000` after last decimal point

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(TIME,STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(OBRGTM,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')),8) as OBRGTM
```

To test:

```
DECLARE @TimeString NUMERIC

SET @TimeString = 232320

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(TIME,STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@TimeString,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')),8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was an integer, you could use integer division to calculate the number of seconds since midnight and make it a datetime that can easlily be formatted:

```
DECLARE @OBRGTM int = 123456;
SELECT DATEADD(second, @OBRGTM - 40*(@OBRGTM/100 + 60*(@OBRGTM/10000)), 0);
```

**Added:**

For those who are interested in the mathemagic behind this:

If `x` is the integer consisting of the digits `hhmmss`, then let's use integer division and define `x' := x/100` and `x" := x/10000`. This way, `x'` will be the integer `hhmm` and `x"` will be just the hours (`hh`).

Now, we can retrieve the seconds (`ss`), minutes (`mm`) and hours (`hh`) of the time hh:mm:ss using:

- `ss = x - 100*x'`
- `mm = x' - 100*x"`
- `hh = x"`

Putting it all together, the total number of seconds after midnight is

```
  ss + 60*mm + 3600*hh
= x - 100*x' + 60*(x' - 100*x") + 3600*x"
= x - 100*x' + 60*x' - 6000*x" + 3600*x"
= x - 40*x' - 2400*x"
= x - 40*(x' + 60*x")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is a string, you can produce a string of the right format using `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(stuff(OBRGTM, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
```

You can convert this to a time using `cast()` or `convert()`:

```
select convert(time, stuff(stuff(OBRGTM, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
```